# Change TFS collection of a Solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to setup TFS server for our Projects. I sucessfully setup and added one of the solution for testing to TFS source controls. But naming were test purposes only so i need to change it. I deleted TFS collections from administration panel and created a new one, but when try to add my solution to new collection it tries to connect old collection and -naturally- cannot find it, and raises error. I do not have same problem for other solutions but only for the solution i tested in the first time.

things I've tried.

- file --> Source Control --> Change Source Control
- Deleting all source control files in solution folder
- Checked .sln file for references to old collection
- Restart the computer.

---

edit:
Ok I have find solution to my problem. 
The thing is Workspace info remained somewhere, I created a TPC and TP same name with the old ones. Then I manually removed Workspace info and then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have find solution to my problem. The thing is Workspace info remained somewhere, I created a TPC and TP same name with the old ones. Then I manually removed Workspace info and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rebind the solution to the new collection using File -> Source Control -> Change Spurce Control. There you have to unbind all projects and rebind them to the new collection.

Comment: Is the project already added to the source control of the new TPC?

Comment: solution and all projects' server binding is set to <No Server> when i click bind, it tries to bind to old TPC and cannot find it.

Comment: The new server is successfully configured in the team explorer?

Comment: yes i do not have a problem with other solutions. Only the first one i used for testing.